Dose it order by primary key when value of secondary index is identical
ref：
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/order-by-optimization.html
if InnoDB table, the table primary key is implicitly part of the index. Dose it order by primary key when value of secondary index is identical?
could you help me answer this question
some references would be better, thanks.

It orders by whatever column you specify in the ORDER BY clause.

Without an ORDER BY, the output will be in whatever order it feels like.
